# Password string validation : has 8 characters atleast 1 character, 1 number & 1 special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to create validation on password string that is : at least 8 characters with at least 1 a-z letter, 1 at least 0-9 number and 1 at least special character like &,#,%,@ etc.

Comment: Have you searched the site for possible duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use very [simple regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to formulate these requirements, and test if every of them [match the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```
var input = …;
var valid = input.length >= 8 // at least 8 characters
              && /[a-z]/.test(input) // contains a lowercase letter
              && /\d/.test(input) // contains a digit
              && /[^\w\s]/.test(input); // contains something that is not a letter, underscore, digit, or whitespace
```

Comment: This can be also written as a series of anchored lookeaheads, which is basically the regex way to express "and" conditions (see the top answer in the linked thread).

Comment: @thg435: Yes, I know that but it's a pain to read/understand for everyone who did not master regex or is even new to JS at all :-)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is it really for not advising an overcomplicated regex?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Your answer is correct.